# Receive a parameter from a page navigation

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation

I'm calling the `Navigate(Uri, Object)` method on a `Frame`, like this:

```
frame.Navigate(new Uri("..."), myParameter);
```

How can I access the `myParameter` object on the page that gets loaded?

I have tried accessing `NavigationService` in the **constructor**, however the service is null:

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //This is null
    NavigationService.Navigated += NavigationService_Navigated;
}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of overload forms for Frame.Navigate method. Following works perfectly. You can follow the same.

```
// Source page
frame.Navigate(new MyPage(myParameter));

// Target page
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public MyPage(TypeOfParameter myParameter) : this()
{
   // use myParameter here
}
```

Comment: Although this is a valid option, requirements force me to use `Navigate(Uri, Object)`. Any other ideas?